# Issue with wp-all-import images take toooo long

Tags: wordpress, image, csv, woocommerce, wpallimport

First of all, sorry for my english.

We try to import a csv file with almost 1000 records using wp-all-import plugin. Every row has a post_name, post_content, post_date..., product_cat, product_images (they are products of woocommerce) and every product has a 5 or 6 images. If we try to upload the 1000 products without image the all process take a 10 minutes (We think this is too long time to 1000 records only). But when wy try to make the same process importing the images this process take almost 10 hours (The images has to being downloaded but we notice this is not the problem. Importing, download the image and create the image all this actions is in the same time). The images in average has 1600x1600. That means the importation drive 6000 images.

Wy made us nuts with this problem. We extend the memory in the server to 2GB, the timeout we extend to 100.000 seconds, we change apache to ngnix (This is the actual server)

We don't know if the problem is the server or not or if the wordpress when try to attach the images or if there are another way to improve this issue or if the thumbnail creation that breaks the process. All plugins are disable (obviously less the wp-all-import plugin)

If there are another way to make this? We appreciate all your help guys. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Please try to disable all other plugins and then upload CSV may be there is any conflict with the plugins.

Comment: Hi @Pratikbhatt, thanks for your help. That also we made. Let me update the question to put that

Comment: It might be the post-processing of every image. If you have 6,000 images and each image is converted into various sizes, I don't think memory (RAM) is your only problem, but rather processing power. Not sure what your hoster's specs are in terms of CPU, but if WP is configured with just 3 additional sizes (large, medium, thumbnail) this will result in 18,000 image conversions at least. If this is a VPS, or regular web hosting with shared CPU, you're out of luck.

Comment: Hi @Damocles I think your right. We disabled most additional sizes and it is a faster. This is a cloud server but not as powerful as other servers we use. It is true that the other more powerful servers run the process much faster.